# Браузер не применяет стили

Tags: css

Здравствуйте.

Не могу разобраться в чем причина, но есть некоторая CMS ни кода которой (не мое), ни названия (попросту не знаю) я сообщить не могу, установилась нормально, база задана верно, все работает, кроме стилей.

Например, берем FireBug, он показывает, что все .css файлы загружены, показывает их содержимое, но не применяет их ни к одному из элементов.

Почти та же байда творится с Оперой, правда кое-какие стили она все же загружать может, а некоторые остаются без внимания.
Говорят, что на других серверах, например, Денвер, работает, а на моем Апаче, не хочет. Причем самое загадочное для меня остается то, что просто стили не применяются, доступ есть, контент есть.

Подключение файлов тоже верное, все вида:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://link/template/default.css" type="text/css" />
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, по какой причине может возникать подобное? Прошу прощения за столь размытое описание.

Comment: стили в head добавляются?

и + пара строк из стилей пригодилась бы (мож там мешанина классов или явно указаны левые теги, типа `div.notice {}` и `<span class="notice">`)

Вообще можно сохранить как "веб-страница, полностью" и выложить куда-нибудь, быстрее будет.

Comment: Хм, спасибо, @Sh4dow, меня осенила идея, и теперь вопрос может перекочевать на РутКод ибо теперь он относится к неверной выдаче сервером стилей, вместо `Content-Type: text/css` сервер все выдает в `Content-Type: text/plain`

Comment: Кстати, это только на cms или вообще на всем сервере? В первом случае это какая-то стремная аномалия. во втором удивительно, что только сейчас замечено.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.htaccess / httpd.conf

```
AddType text/css .css
```

=)

Comment: Это только на этой CMS. Вот сижу ищу где. Ибо такой тип у меня валяется в mime.types присоединенном к серверу.

Comment: Смотрите .htaccess, там может быть что-то типа

    rewriterule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

или просто перехват стилей. можно еще поиском по файлам пробежать по запросам "text/plain", "header(" и подобным.

И еще [на всякий случай](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=301514)

Comment: На самом деле вы правы, скорее всего в этом дело и было, а у меня какой-то корявый стоял mime.types или даже не знаю, что это было. Но теперь оно работает, спасибо.

Comment: Отлично) Это, конечно, костыль, но вроде крепенький, стоять должен)

Comment: Отчего это костыль? какая разница - прописать типы в конфигах сервера или в .htaccess?

Comment: Костыль в том, что по-хорошему надо было найти, где cms перекрывает контент-тайп стилей и исправить там. Что-то мне подсказывает, что это не единственное проявление оригинальности разрабов)

Comment: @Sh4dow, вы видимо не поняли, это была, скорее, моя ошибка, какой-то леваковый mime.types подключил в Апаче, и вот такая странная хрень вылилась.